# Select all elements that are NOT "this" in an each function with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, button

I have a bunch of buttons on a page and when one is clicked, one of it's parent elements to have a class removed ("program-selector") and a class added ("opened"). *But*, I also want to do the opposite for all the other parents of the other buttons that were not clicked.

So when a button is clicked, it's parent gains the "opened" class and loses the "program-collector" class, and the rest of the button's parents lose the "opened" class and gain the "program collector" class.

Below is the code I tried using but to no avail. I must be using the .not() selector incorrectly but I don't know how to use it in this instance.

```
$(".faculty-panel a").each(function(l,tab) {
            $(tab).click(function(){    
              if($(tab).hasClass("collapsed")){
                $(this).closest(".program-collector").addClass("opened");
                $(this).closest(".program-collector").removeClass("program-collector");
                $(tab).not($(this)).closest(".opened").addClass("program-collector");
                $(tab).not($(this)).closest(".opened").removeClass("opened");

}
```

And the HTML...

```
<div class="program-collector" id="<?=($content['field_curriculum_program_title'][0]['#title'])?>">
<div id="panel-wrap">

    <div class="panel">

        <h3 class="lg-screen-prg-title"><?=$content['field_curriculum_program_title'][0]['#title']?></h3>
        <div class="panel-heading faculty-panel" role="tab" id="heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" class="collapsed">
            <?= render($content['field_curriculum_program_title'][0]['#title']); ?>
            </a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse faculty-prg" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading">
        <?php print render($content['field_faculty_member']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML it's very hard to answer this kind of question in a useful way.

Comment: Yow. Show your HTML so we can suggest alternatives to your `parent()` family tree up there.

Comment: Better, build a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @isherwood - No love for stack snippets?

Comment: I find Fiddles so much easier to work with. My $.02.

Comment: instead of going parent().parent().parent() do $(this).closest(".parentContainer") or something along those lines to simplify your javascript.

Comment: Step 1. set all containers to the condition that you want all but that one container in, Step 2, then reset the one container back to the appropriate state.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to isolate a certain element using `:not` selector in your case. You can simply use the following expression to achieve what you are trying to do.

**Option 1 :** Add-remove classes.

```
   $(".faculty-panel a").on("click",function() {  

    $(".faculty-panel a").closest('.opened').addClass('program-collector').removeClass('opened');  // find the parent of all the matching elements which has class 'opened' and add class 'program-collector' while removing class 'opened'

  $(this).closest('.program-collector').addClass('opened').removeClass('program-collector'); // find the parent of the button clicked and add class 'opened' while removing class 'program-collector'
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3hvvdht9/1/

**Option 2 :** Using `toggleClass()`

```
$(".faculty-panel a").on("click",function() {  

    $(".faculty-panel a").closest('.opened').toggleClass('program-collector opened');  

  $(this).closest('.program-collector').toggleClass('opened program-collector');
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3hvvdht9/2/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)